# Pros and cons of a conical fermentor

Tags: fermenter, conical-fermenter

What are the pros and cons of a conical fermentor compared to buckets or carboys?

Comment: also http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/why-would-i-want-a-conical-fermenter

Answer (score 8):

Assuming you're talking about a stainless steel conical, off the top of my head...

Pros:

- Technically easier to collect and harvest yeast
- Can be more hygenic (less chance of scratches that can harbour yeast/bacteria)
- Less fragile than glass carboy (but possibly more than buckets)
- If it's pressure rated, you can cap it towards end of fermentation for natural carbonation
- Looks fancier
- Can dump trub and cold break prior to pitching

Cons:

- Cost
- If not jacketed and in a warmer climate, need a bigger fridge to house in for temp control
- Presumably heavier, so not as easy to move around for cleaning, etc

Comment: I'm now fermenting in 10 gallon Cornelius kegs. All the pros (except looking fancy) and none of the cons. I can harvest yeast through the "out" port, and use a spunding value on the gas port to cap the fermentation and carbonate.

Comment: Yep, fermenting in a keg would be very similar. Just added another pro of being able to dump trub & break material before pitching. You could probably do that in a keg too. I'd argue you could get a cleaner harvest from the conical, but at a home brewing level, it's probably not that big a deal.

Answer (score 1):

Stainless conical fermentors don't let in light or UV rays and unlike plastic, it's impermeable to oxygen.